# Cakephp 2 using post data can't login properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a site let's say it's called flat.dev. If I login from the site directly it works fine and go to flat.dev/dashboard.

But, let's say I have another site, called test.tst where in the site there is a link with form data, where it tried to login to flat.dev e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go2flat(){
 window.open('','flat','width=800,height=600,scrollbars=1,status=1,menubar=1,location=1,toolbar=1,personalbar=1,resizable=1')
 document.j.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="j" action="http://flat.dev/users/login/" target="flat" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data[User][email]" value="administrator@abc.net">
<input type="hidden" name="data[User][password]" value="abc">
</form>

<li><a class="menu_l" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="go2flat()">Flat <font color=red>(New)</font></a></li>
```

If I click the link from test.tst, it will automaticly redirect to flat.dev/users/login with an error saying "you can't access that" like it failed to log in. If I change the url to "flat.dev/dashboard", it will failed. HOWEVER, if I open a new tab, and try the same link, it will login. what is the problem in here? My code is standard cake login e.g: $this->Auth->login();

and sometimes after I logout, and I open a new tab, it still logged in. I have to logout again to be truly log out.

Recently I developed cakeshell and use this permission on bootstrap.php, otherwise it will give me SPLInfo warning.. could this be the cause?

```
Cache::config('_cake_core_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => 'cake_core_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'persistent' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));

Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    'engine' => $engine,
    'prefix' => 'cake_model_',
    'path' => CACHE . 'models' . DS,
    'serialize' => ($engine === 'File'),
    'duration' => $duration,
    'mask' => 0666
));

// short  
Cache::config('short', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

// long
Cache::config('long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

Comment: Where is the form post button? And why are those input fields hidden?
You should rather post the PHP code than the final HTML output btw. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: @mark it's a standard html post, the 2nd website is normal html page. so no php code. as for version it's 2.2.1. it is hidden so user see it as link instead of a form.

Comment: Isn't it a known issue with some browsers, that forms aren't valid without the actual submit button present? Have you tried adding it back in if that works then? At least IE I know once had that issue.

Comment: As documentation, its good to define Cache::config on bootstrap.php..

Comment: I found out this happened due to I have this on bootstrap: 
define('FULL_BASE_URL', 'http://www.flat.dev'); If I removed this code, it work normal, but then.. I will have a problem wil CLI Command for shell script, because full_base => true, for html link don't give the true url

Comment: You cant put this in core.php. i think you want to declare on constant.